# JMeter Maven Bamboo

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, bamboo, jmeter-maven-plugin

My Bamboo instance is using Maven version 3.3.3. But I keep getting this error

> Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.0.3:jmeter (jmeter-tests) on project test: The plugin com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.0.3 requires Maven version 3.1.1

This is an extract from the pom.xml file

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <testFilesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/jmeter</testFilesDirectory>
                <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
                <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you post your bamboo setup as well?

Comment: Bamboo usually creates a fairly detailed log, which includes maven version. Can you post it here please?